# Не отображаются изображения на сайте

Tags: дефект, статус-не-воспроизводится, imgur

Ни в телефоне, ни в Mozile ни в Chrome не отображаются изображения которые вставляют в вопрос, при попытке перейти по ссылке изображения, выдает ошибку о защищенном подключении. Может что-то в настройках браузеров надо поменять, или баг на самом `stackoverflow`? Никто не сталкивался?

**UPD**

> Во время загрузки страницы соединение с сервером было сброшено.
>   Страница, которую вы пытаетесь просмотреть, не может быть отображена, так как достоверность полученных данных не может быть
>   проверена.
>   Пожалуйста, свяжитесь с владельцами веб-сайта и проинформируйте их об этой проблеме.

Comment: выдает ошибку о защищенном подключении - смотрите детали ошибки. если ни у кого, кроме вас, ошибки нет, значит ваш провайдер шалит и пытается влезть в https

Comment: @PashaPash Дополнил вопрос

Comment: У меня всё загружает и отображает. И даже открывается картинка при клике после загрузки :) Опишите по шагам, как повторить проблему, если она ещё имеет место быть.

Comment: @alexolut Мда, не работало все это время, задал тут вопрос, и вдруг картинки начали отображаться. хм

Comment: С хостингом изображений imgur вообще бывают проблемы с некоторой периодичностью, но обычно они быстро исправляются.

Comment: @alexolut ну так у меня не отображались изображения вообще, ни на телефоне, ни на виндовсе ни на линуксе в разных браузерах. Благо, зато сейчас вдруг все заработало, видать скрытые агенты SO быстро пофиксили))

Comment: Скорее всего проблема вовсе была не на стороне SO. imgur сторонний сервис.

Comment: @alexolut Ну тогда почему вдруг заработало? Я ничего не делал. Только как сюда с вопросом обратился само по себе заработало).

Comment: Никто не знает почему оно работало, почему сломалось и почему заработало вновь. Так во многих программных проектах происходит :)

Comment: Возможно, конкретный узел CDN с геопривязкой сбоил, поэтому не работало только в некоторых регионах; как его починили, у них тоже заработало.

Comment: @D-side кстати перестало после этого работать опять, как человек начинающий программировать знаю, что "само по себе" ничего не бывает, но я абсолютно ничего не делал, после вопроса изображения стали отображаться, но на следующий день опять перестали, в общем решил оставить)